# call, v-directive after button clicked

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make `focus` on input when button clicked. To achieve this, using `v-directive` locally. But couldn't make properly. How can I make to directive apply after I clicked the button.

**template**

```
<td class="member-item">
    <vs-button
        @click="edit_name()"
        v-show="!edit"
    >
        something something
    </vs-button>

    <input v-show="edit" focus type="text" v-focus>
</td>
```

**script**

```
directives: {
    focus: {
        inserted: function (el) {
           el.focus()
        }
    }
},
data(){
    return {
        edit: false,
    }
},
methods: {
    edit_name(){
        this.edit = true;
    },
},
```

when I click the `button`, that `button` will change with the `input` and input will be focused.  Is anyone guide me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to pass `edit` flag as value to `focus` directive and the trigger the `el.focus()` on the current binding element using [hook function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions) like:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data() {
    return {
      edit: false,
    }
  },
  directives: {
    focus: {
      inserted: function(el) {
        el.focus()
      },
      update: function(el, {value}) {
        if (!value) return;
        Vue.nextTick(() => el.focus());
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    edit_name() {
      this.edit = true;
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp">
  <button @click="edit_name()">Click Me!</button><br>
  <input v-show="edit" focus type="text" v-focus="edit" placeholder="Enter Name">
</div>
```

For more info:

- [Custom Directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply focus on the input field after clicking the button

Add a `ref` value to the field

```
<input v-show="edit" type="text" ref="input">
```

Then inside the method

```
methods: {
    edit_name(){
        this.edit = true;
        this.$refs.input.focus();
    },
},
```

This will focus on the field on clicking the button.

Comment: thank you for the another approach, but trying to make with directive.

Answer (score 0):

about your snippet, you can use `v-if` instead of `v-show` without need to use `directive`